# A knockout tournament

Tags: mathematics

$12345$ players take part in a knockout tournament. In each round players are paired up; each pair plays a game with the winning player advancing to the next round (no ties). If there are an odd number of players at the start of a round, one is randomly selected to automatically progress. This continues until one player is delared champion.

How many games are played in total?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In every game one person loses. There is only one winner, so there must be $12344$ losers. Therefore there are $12344$ games.

Answer (score 14):

Let $a_n$ be the number of players at the beginning of the $n$-th round, so that $a_1 = 12345$. Then $a_{n+1} = \lceil \frac{a_n}{2} \rceil$, and the number of games played in round $n$ is $g_n = \lfloor \frac{a_n}{2}\rfloor$.

We thus have the following sequence for $a_n$:

$$12345, 6173, 3087, 1544, 772, 386, 193, 97, 49, 25, 13, 7, 4, 2, 1$$

And the following sequence for $g_n$:

$$6172, 3086, 1543, 772, 386, 193, 96, 48, 24, 12, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0$$

For a total of $12344$ games.

Comment: You overthought it a bit...

Comment: @Deusovi Right, your solution is much much simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Yes but I would argue that this is the proper math going through calculating how many games for a tree tournament.

Comment: And now you know why the claim at the end of Bloodsport that the real life Frank Dux knocked out 56 consecutive opponents in a single elimination bracketed tournament is so ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is **`12344`**.
>  For any number `n` it will be *`n-1`*.

**Explanation**

Since this is a knockout round.At the end of each round, half players are getting eliminated.

Let `N = 2^k` where *`N`* is the total number of Players.

In First Round, We will have `N/2` matches, in second round `N/4` matches. So, at the end of last round we will have `1` match.

Total number of matches = `N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ....2 + 1` which is a standard Geometric Progression Problem.

The Sum will be `1*(2^k - 1)/(2-1) = 2^k - 1 = N-1`

Similarly, You can generalize this to any 'N'.

**What If N is not power of 2 ?**

For Generalizing it for any `N`, Remember that we can break any `N` in powers of `2`.

**Ex- Let `N = 1000`**,

I can write **`1000 = 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 8`**.
Now, Doing as above, We will have **`511+ 255 + 127 + 63 + 31 + 7 = 994`** matches. We will be left with 6 people.

Similarly, `6 = 2 + 2 + 2` , Then we will have 3 more matches i.e 997 and left with 3 people.

Now for `3` people, split as `2` and `1` which will take 2 matches.
The total number of matches will be `994 + 3 + 2 = 999.`

Now, You can generalize it.

Hope that helps. :)